# Docker swarm using host=net

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I need to run container from `docker stack` using the `host` network.
So I created network in my Compose file using doc [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#host-or-none):

```
...
version: '3.3'

networks:
  foo-services:
    driver: overlay
  node-exporters:
    external:
      name: host
...
```

And used it in a service's `networks`:

```
...
  node-exporter:
    image: prom/node-exporter
    networks:
      - node-exporters
...
```

But after I deployed stack using `docker stack deploy -c foo-services.yml foo-services` - all services started (they use `foo-services` network) but `node-exporter` always stays in the `Created` status:

```
root@jm-swarm-manager:/home/setevoy# docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                           COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
20938efc615d        prom/node-exporter:latest       "/bin/node_exporter …"   5 seconds ago       Created                                         foo-services_node-exporter.rqjn8rhye96f54c1n1heo8zbl.a9k4qjegrqt4etn21ode8xdfl
```

And logs are empty.

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: How did you create the network 'host'?

Comment: It comes by default with the docker installation